# Java File encryption, can't get it to accept file input

Tags: java, encryption, file-io, inputstream, outputstream

I'm trying to do simple file encryption with Java right now. Nothing serious and hardcore, just very basic. Right now I need to Encode the file by adding 5 to every byte in the file. The program prompts the user to enter an input file name and an output file name and saves the encrypted version of the input file to the output file.

Here's my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class EncryptFiles {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a file to encrypt: ");

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(input.next());
     //  BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(input.next())));

        System.out.print("Enter the output file: ");

        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(input.next());
     //  BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(input.next())));

        int value;

        while ((value = in.read()) != -1) {
          output.write(value + 5);
        }

        input.close();
        output.close();

    }
}
```

I've doen the regular FileInputStream as well as the BufferedInputStream and both of them give me the same error.

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Me.txt (The
> system cannot find the file specified)    at
> java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)   at
> java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)  at
> java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)  at
> EncryptFiles.main(EncryptFiles.java:10) Java Result: 1
```

I put the file Me.txt in the C: directory, i've put in documents I've also tried put it in the Java src folder. I've tried to type out the exact file path and nothing works. I've done it like this `C:/Users/Richard/Documents/Me.txt` and like this `C:\Users\Richard\Documents\Me.txt` But no matter how i try it, i get the same error.

Thanks for future assistance :)

Comment: I've tried that as well, and the same error occurs

Comment: Just tried it, still an error

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. Is Me.txt actually Me.txt.txt? By default, Windows hides file extensions, so if you name a file Me.txt it will actually be named Me.txt.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the way you instantiating the `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` to

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(input.nextLine()));

FileOutputStream in = new FileOutputStream(new File(input.nextLine()));
```

and use the full path as input like `C:/Users/Richard/Documents/Me.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this -

```
String fileInPath = input.next().trim();
System.out.println("Opening file " + fileInPath);
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileInPath);
```

I'd probably use something more like this myself; you should always close your resources.

```
String fileInPath = input.next().trim();
System.out.println("Opening file " + fileInPath);
FileInputStream in = null;
try {
  File fileIn = new File(fileInPath);
  if (fileIn != null && fileIn.canRead()) {
    in = new FileInputStream(fileIn);
  } else {
    System.out.println("Could not open file " + fileInPath);
  }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
} finally {
  if (in != null) {
    try {
      in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, i've figured it out though through helpful comments :)